# Necesito crear una columna en otra tabla pero con el mismo nombre de id en mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Necesito crear una columna en la tabla comprobantes con el mismo nombre de id de la tabla descuento ( iddescuento) y que los datos que existen ahi se relacionen

Lo que trato de hacer es que la iddescuento de la tabal descuento, este relacionada con la iddescuento de la tabla comprobante.

Intente creando una tabla con el mismo nombre en la tabla de comprobantes pero al momento de hacer el fk no me permite. Que puedo realizar.

ESTOY UTILIZANDO ESTA SENTENCIA:

```
INSERT INTO comprovantes (iddesceuntos) 
SELECT descuentos.iddesceuntos FROM descuentos
```

> 1054 - Unknown column 'iddesceuntos' in 'field list'

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

El error que tienes se deriva precisamente de que trataste de usar una columna que no existe en dicha tabla para asignarle un valor

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

- Primero debes crear la columna que funcionará como llave foránea y vínculo entre la tabla `descuentos` y la tabla `comprobantes` quedando del siguiente modo:

Código:

```
ALTER TABLE comprobantes ADD COLUMN descuento_id INT(11) NOT NULL AFTER valordescuento;
```

- Ahora necesitas vincular dicha columna con su equivalente en la tabla `descuentos` de esta forma

Código:

```
ALTER TABLE comprobantes ADD FOREIGN KEY (descuento_id) REFERENCES comprobantes(idduescuentos);
```

De manera que:

- Agregas a la tabla secundaria una columna que será unión con la tabla dependiente
- A esa columna recién agregada la vas a declarar por medio de un `CONSTRAINT` para indicar que funcionará como *llave foránea*
- Necesitas ahora si tener registros en la llave primaria de la tabla `descuentos`
- Extra: considera que tienes un par de detalles escribiendo mal el nombre de las columnas; caso concreto revisa la llave primaria de la tabla `descuentos` la escribiste mal
- Ahora si con la columna recién creada tendrás un vínculo entre las 2 tablas, lo cual facilitará que puedas guardar un enlace simbólico entre ambas

> Nota importante, antes de proceder con un `ALTER` que modificará la estructura de la tabla procura hacer un respaldo de tu base de datos para mantener la integridad.

Por otro lado aunque en la mayoría de los casos siempre esta esta configuración, no esta demás su uso:

- El motor de dichas tablas debe ser `InnoDB` para que la intención de relación por medio del `CONSTRAINT` funcione

**Referencias**

- [Motor InnoDB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-innodb-tables.html)
- [Respaldo en MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-backup-excerpt/5.7/en/mysqldump-sql-format.html)

Comment: Hay que indicar que las tablas tienen que estar en el engine `InnoDB` para que las restricciones funcionen, si están en `MyISAM` no funcionan. Si las tablas tienen datos hay que hacer una copia de seguridad antes de modificarlas.

Comment: #1005 - No puedo crear tabla `hotel_2020`.`comprovantes` (Error: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Comment: ALTER TABLE comprovantes ADD FOREIGN KEY (descuento_id) REFERENCES comprovantes(iddesceuntos)

Comment: ¿Creaste primero la columna `descuento_id`, ya revisaste que no tengas algún nombre de tabla o columna mal escrit?

Comment: El motor de las tablas son InnoDB pero me da ese error "Error: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

Comment: Sigue fallando, las columnas y las tablas estan todo bien escritas

Comment: Ok y cual sería la solucion a ese problema de Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

Comment: Si es llave primaria el iddesceuntos

Comment: Te envio las capturas de las tablas @Aprendiz: Tabla Descuentos  https://i.ibb.co/wWh6hQY/1.png Tabla comprovantes: https://i.ibb.co/y0x3M5L/2.png https://i.ibb.co/xmbvQ7H/4.png

Comment: Ya me confundí en tus capturas veo la llave foránea creada

Comment: pero el descuento_id no tiene llave foranea